# ubuntu 16.04, wired connection suddenly lost

Tags: 16.04, connection, wired

I'm an absolute novice to Linux/Ubuntu and network, don't even know how to use vi editor yet. Just installed ubuntu 16.04 for about a week and happy learning online. However the wired connection, which has been fine for a week, lost all of a sudden when I turned on my computer today. I tried to find some solution by googling, and noticed that someone here asked the similar question couple of months ago, which turned out just bad wires. So I checked my hardware, changed 3 cable wires, one is brand new came with my new router (Netgear AC1900 R7000). the following is the info I gathered by reading some posts

`ifconfig -a`:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1a:6b:36:35:51  
   UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
  RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
  TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
  collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
  RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
  Interrupt:20 Memory:fe000000-fe020000 


lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
  inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
  inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
  UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
  RX packets:2390 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
  TX packets:2390 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
  collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
  RX bytes:202319 (202.3 KB)  TX bytes:202319 (202.3 KB)


wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:13:e8:21:fd:c9  
  UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
  RX packets:4047 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
  TX packets:3489 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
  collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
  RX bytes:3294308 (3.2 MB)  TX bytes:485753 (485.7 KB)
```

some ping test:

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8
connect: Network is unreachable


$ ping 192.168.1.1
connect: Network is unreachable
```

`route -n`:

```
    Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
```

`ip route show` returns nothing.

**I could get online by wireless, however the results of ping tests are very odd. It keeps running, I have to break it by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>**

```
$ ping 192.168.1.1

PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=2.00 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.33 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=1.33 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=1.33 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=1.36 ms
......

64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=17 ttl=64 time=0.667 ms

35 packets transmitted, 35 received, 0% packet loss, time 34019ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.667/1.024/2.008/0.355 ms
```

same for `ping 8.8.8.8`, just the last 2 lines different

```
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
16 packets transmitted, 15 received, 6% packet loss, time 15023ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 9.357/11.939/30.631/5.519 ms
```

`route -n` and `ip route show` gave the following result under wireless connection.

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlan0

$ ip route show

default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0  proto static  metric 600 

169.254.0.0/16 dev wlan0  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.8  metric 600
```

I have not installed or removed anything from last night when everything running normal and alright. I don't know why all of a sudden the wired connection lost, even under wireless connection things don't look right, though I could get online - like post this asking-for-help post.

If you need more information, please be very detail and specific, like what should I type in command line, how do I get out of vi or any other easy editor I could temporarily use.

=========================update========================

the output of interfaces and NetworkManager.conf

```
    cat /etc/network/interfaces
    # interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

    cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
    [main]
    plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
    dns=dnsmasq

    [ifupdown]
    managed=false
```

---

So my interfaces was looking like

```
    # interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback
```

Do I delete these 2 lines or just added your above 2 line in-middle like this

```
    # interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
    auto lo
    auto eth0
    iface eth0 inet dhcp
    iface lo inet loopback
```

---

Right now my interfaces file is as below, but still no wired connection after re-boot (which took about 6 mins)

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Comment: `ping`'s default behaviour is to run forever until you kill it. If you want it to terminate after N packets, use `ping -c N`.

Comment: Your eth0 seems to not getting configured. Can you post the output of your `/etc/network/interfaces` and `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` you can do that by typing in `cat /path/to/file`

Comment: @Ziazis, thank you. i posted the output in my original post. (i'm a bit confused how to post on this forum).

Answer (score 1):

Your `/etc/network/interfaces` has no entry for your eth0 connection so it can't really start something there.

If you add the following lines it will be started during boot.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

If you want to have a static IP for your client you can also type in a static IP.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address 192.168.x.x   
  netmask 255.255.255.0  
  gateway 192.168.x.x
  dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

Note that you have of course to ajust the IP's to you network.

Comment: so my interfaces was looking like

Comment: @Wing I don't understand your latest comment. What do you mean?

Comment: @nick I have trouble using comments here. a little frustrated to post here. guess mod has editted my post, the pasted my last deleted post at the end of my  original post.

Comment: @Ziazis, I did what you told me - please see the end of my original post, mod has attached my last deleted post, but still no wired connection after reboot

Comment: the boot up takes exceedingly long, about 6 mins, after I did that change in interfaces file, wired connection still not working. "ethenet connection" is greyed-out, "wired", which was listed before under "edit connections", is no longer listed there.